# How to securely store Connection String details in VBA

Tags: vba, connection-string

I have an Excel Template that has hardcoded Ms Access MDB path in the VBA code used to connect to the Access tables and save, retrieve data.

I migrated the MS Access Database over to SQL Server with Integrated Authentication for the Excel Template Users.

My question is, What is the Recommend Way / Best Practice for storing the SQL Server DB connection string and retreiving it in Excel 2007 VBA to save and retrieve data?

In the past, I have done the following.

1. Use a Registry Key setting that has the Connection String. Then in the VBA, write a function that reads the registry key and returns the connection string.
2. Have a "Settings" hidden sheet within the Excel Template, with named cell for the connection string. Read the connection string in VBA by accessing that named range.
3. Use a .INI txt file that goes with the Excel template. (This is not ideal and I want to avoid this as it builds a dependency on that external file)

I don't like # 1 because I want to avoid writing to/reading from Registry if possible.
# 2 feels ok, thought I am not sure if there is a better "cleaner" way for doing this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: See my answer to thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987333/excel-vba-secure-way-to-get-users-database-login-password-for-connection-string/2018970#2018970

Comment: @Remou. thanks.
@MikeD. Thanks, I checked that out. Is using the registry though, and I am trying to avoid that. Because troubleshooting a prod issue would become a nightmare when using registry settings (since it will be user machine specific settings)....

Comment: I've found the registry to be a great place for it, but that does require additional set-up for each user. I can understand why you would want to avoid that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is what I would do safely store connection string credentials

Download and install [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows (*FREE*)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-windows-desktop)

**Open it as Administrator** and create a New Project. Select *`Visual C#`* then *`Class Library`* and rename it to *`HiddenConnectionString`*

[image]

In the *Solution Explorer*, rename *`Class1.cs`* to *`MyServer.cs`*

[image]

Right click your *`MyConnection`* project in the *Solution Explorer* and select *`Add Reference`*

Type `activeX` in the search box and tick the `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library`

[image]

Copy and paste the below code into the *`MyServer.cs`* completely replacing whatever is in the file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using ADODB;

namespace HiddenConnectionString
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
    Guid("2FCEF713-CD2E-4ACB-A9CE-E57E7F51E72E")]
    public interface IMyServer
    {
        Connection GetConnection();
        void Shutdown();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("57BBEC44-C6E6-4E14-989A-B6DB7CF6FBEB")]
    public class MyServer : IMyServer
    {
        private Connection cn;

        private string cnStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=SERVER\\INSTANCE; Initial Catalog=default_catalog; User ID=your_username; Password=your_password";

        public MyServer()
        {
        }

        public Connection GetConnection()
        {
            cn = new Connection();
            cn.ConnectionString = cnStr;
            cn.Open();
            return cn;
        }

        public void Shutdown()
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Locate the `cnStr` variable in the code and **update** your connection string details.

Right click the `*HiddenConnectionString`* solution in the *Solution Explorer* and select Properties.

Click the *`Application`* tab on the left side, then *`Assembly Info`* and tick `Make Assembly COM-Visible`

[image]

Click the `*Build*` from the menu on the left and tick `Register For COM Interop`

[image]

Note: If you are developing for 64-bit Office then make sure you change the *`Platform Target`* on the *Build* menu to `x64`! This is mandatory for 64-bit Office COM libraries to avoid any ActiveX related errors.

---

Right click the *`HiddenConnectionString`* in the *Solution Explorer* and select *`Build`* from the menu.

If everything went OK then your `HiddenConnectionString.dll` and `HiddenConnectionString.tlb` should be successfully generated. Go to this path now

```
C:\Users\administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HiddenConnectionString\HiddenConnectionString\bin\Debug
```

and you should see your files.

[image]

---

Now open Excel and go to VBE. Click `Tools` and select `References`.

Click the <kbd>Browse</kbd> button and navigate to the `HiddenConnectionString.tlb`.

Also, add references to `Microsoft ActiveX Object 6.1 Library` - this is so you can use ADODB library.

[image]

Now right click anywhere in the *Project Explorer* window and *Insert* a new *`Module`*

copy and paste the below code to it

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim myCn As MyServer
    Set myCn = New MyServer

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open "Select * from [TABLE_NAME]", myCn.GetConnection

    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    myCn.Shutdown

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set myCn = Nothing

    Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Replace the `[TABLE_NAME]` with an actual table name in your database.

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or hit the green *play* button on the ribbon.

[image]

If everything went OK, you should now see the returned Table on your spreadsheet.

my sample:

[image]

---

As you can see. Adding references to your own COM-library and storing the login credentials and other sensitive data inside the compiled `.dll` protects your data(connection string). It's very difficult to decompile the `*.dll` file to get any sensible information from it. There are various coding *techniques* to protect your `*.dll` even more but I am not going to go into details now. This itself achieves what you asked for.

`myCn.GetConnection` returns the `ADODB.Connection` object that was initialized inside the referenced COM library. No Excel user will be presented with the connection string or sensitive data (actually nobody else neither).

You can modify the C# code to accept parameters from VBA i.e. login, password, initial catalog, query to execute etc... if you have users with different privileges on the instance of your SQL Server it wouldn't be a bad idea to allow people to log in.

---

Note: there is no error handling added in the C# code and VBA. I would strongly recommending working on it if you're planning to use the technique I have described above.

---

Comment: "I have also posted this answer on my blog"
- Bookmarked!
Thanks for your amazing contributions in these types of threads.

Comment: @mehow Thanks for the detailed answer. As you can see, this was over 3 years ago and I am no longer working on that project or client, but I still accepted your answer. It looks like it will work.

Comment: @Shiva thanks. I decided to give this answer anyway because I couldn't find an answer myself at some point in time. Hopefully it will serve others well :)

Comment: Does this mean anyone get the dll file can use it to connect?

Comment: @Yiping it depends how you set the entire environment up. Normally, you would probably allow only certain domain users to be able to establish a connection with your SQL/any server, wouldn't you? If you used windows authentication / or per user authentication you probably wouldnt even need to hide your connection string cuz you wouldnt require a username and password...

Comment: I would say its easy to decompile that piece of code to extract the connection string. And if the user really wants he/she can get the connection string with packet sniffer very very easily.

Comment: If I wanted someone else to execute this what references should the user add to his computer? Is there any way to automate all the necessary steps?

Comment: Sorry, this is still only an illusion of security.  In fact it makes it *easier* to bust into your database because you can just reference your COM object and use *that* to get your own raw connection.

Comment: "It's very difficult to decompile the *.dll file to get any sensible information from it." is wrong. It is just a single click with tools like dotPeek, ILSpy, JustDecompile, .NET Reflector, etc. Google for "decompile .NET" - you get many result (without entering the "dark-net"). In order to be more secure, you should write your DLL in C++ which is more difficult to decompile.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing it under [`CustomDocumentProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203269%28office.11%29.aspx)?

Note: I am not sure, if the workbook (based on a given template) will inherit the property defined using `CustomDocumentProperties` in the template.