# Hide Connection String details from End-User or Customer in Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, database-connection

I am developing an Excel Report. All the things are working fine. I am using ODBC DSN connection type to connect with Oracle Database. The problem is that When I connect to Database then it will ask for the password. I know there is a option "Save Password" in connection wizard. But If I saved my db password then it will show to the Customer or End-User which is not good.

What I want.. I want to HIDE the password or the whole string [Connection String] from Customer who use the Excel Sheet or view it. Is there any way to do this. I tried macro but it will transfer my file format to *.xlsm, I want to do this in *.xls

Comment: I don't think this is an Oracle question, more of a VB/VBA question. Where is your code?

Comment: I am not sure you can do it safe. Your password will anyway be saved in Excel file and it would be quite easy for hackers to get everything  from it as far as Excel is just a file with your encrypted password with known algorythm.

Comment: see [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19163256/2140173) to hide the connection string details from users.