# Password of connection string in Pass Through Query properties

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am calling oracle stored procedures via Pass Through Query in MS Access.
In pass through query properties we are saving connection string with password. I don't want to allow the user to see the password. 
Is there any way to encrypt the password in pass through query.

[image: QueryProperties.png]

Connection string contains 
 **ODBC;DSN=NEW_ODBC;UID=XXXXX;PWD=XXXXXXX;DBQ=XXXXXX;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;**

I am using docmd to call the pass through query

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_into_table", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

If i remove the PWD from the above string, every time it ask for the password to enter. I heard about the concept to use DSN less connection but i am not sure how to create dsn less connection for odbc. I am using user dsn.

Is there any way to encrypt the password or user can not see the password??

Thanks

Comment: see if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19163256/2140173) helps.

Comment: Have you considered skipping the pass-through and using ADO?

Comment: @ Fionnuala. No i didn't try .please can you tell me how to skip pass through query and use ADO

Answer (score 3):

If you link all your tables and also that of pass-though queries and LEAVE OUT the uid/password, then your quires and linked tables etc. will run just fine. You need to execute JUST ONE logon command at application start.

So in your DSNless re-link code, include the pass-though queries.

How to eliminate the need to include the user id and password in linked tables it outlined here:

Power Tip: Improve the security of database connections

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections/

The above also works for pass-through queries.

The result is then you can execute the pass though query like this in code:

```
Currentdb.Execute "qry_into_table"
```

And you can even pass values to a stored procedure with this code:

```
With Currentdb.QueryDefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "exec sp_MyUpdate " & strParm1
   .execute
End With
```

Note how clean, and how we don't have to deal with connection strings in code with the above.

So the above power tip really eliminates huge amounts of code, eliminates the need to introduce ADO for calling stored procedures, and removes the need of having to deal with messy connection strings in code.