# how to hide connection string from a web query in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to send reports to clients. The report is generated in excel via web query. The draw back is everyone has access to the excel, can see the connection string, which could be used for unauthorized access to other reports. I am considering to add password using VBA. Is there any way that I can remove/hide the connection string from connection->property?

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to hide the string,

Take a look at this great answer on StackOverflow ,[How to securely store Connection String details in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163256/6283475)