# oracle vba trusted connection issue windows 10 64 bit Ms Excel 64bit

Tags: excel, oracle, vba, trustedconnection

```
    Dim con As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim query As String
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    col = 2
    strcon = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" _
    & "Data Source= (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVER_IP)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.Multi-Act.Local))); " _
    & "Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;" _
    & "Trusted_connection=yes"

    con.Open (strcon)
```

I am getting an error called 
"Run Time Error'-2147217887 (80040e21)":
Automation Error

Without trusted connection this code works fine. But trusted connection cant establish a connection. I have ODAC122010Xcopy_x64 installed.

Comment: Answer can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217014/how-to-securely-store-connection-string-details-in-vba)